# iOS subview widget hooked up to multiple controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So, I want to create a reusable widget as a xib and subview that can appear on a set amount of specific screens. This widget will have three buttons, each with an Action.

I want to be able to handle these actions on multiple viewcontrollers.

So say ViewControllerA, ViewControllerD, and ViewControllerF can handle the three button events, each in their own way.

I've created the nib file. How do I import it into the specific viewcontrollers, and then how do I wire up those events?

**EDIT: I know that I could potentially get outlets set up via a viewcontroller, but Apple states that UIViewController is for full-screen views only, and my widget is only taking up a small portion of the screen.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done correctly. And one thing is, In `iOS` it's not widget.It's a `UIView`.

**(Sorry there may be any typo in my code.I have written myself in StackOverflow)**

**Follow Below Steps to finish it..**

1) After you have created the `xib` for the view, then you need to have a `UIView` subclass files.. For example your `xib` name likes this `CustomView.xib` means then create a files like this `CustomView.m` and CustomView.h

2) In your `CustomView.xib` , You need to set the `fileOwner` as your `CustomView.h`.

3) In your `CustomView.m` file, there will be a method like `initWithFrame:` In that method you need to load your xib file like this

```
NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:0];
UIView *currentView = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
[self addSubView:currentView];
```

4) Almost over. In any of your view controller, you can use this xib like

```
CustomView *newSubView = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,55,67)];
[self.view addSubView:newSubView];
```

That's it.. Go on..

Answer (score 0):

You have created a nib file but make sure that you have also created the .h and .m file that will be the controller for that nib file.  You will have to look up how to implement delegate methods which your other view controllers can capture and act on in their own way.  Here is a great tutorial to get you started on making custom classes with custom delegates: [Link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/)

Comment: Hi Kris, Apple states in its guidelines that UIViewController is only meant for full-screen. As the widget is a small item on the screen, it should not have to have the UIViewController implementation. Are you saying that the only way I can access the items via outlet is to have a ViewController? Thanks - Allison

Comment: No you can use a UIView as well, just make a UIView subclass and implement some custom delegate methods as the link that I have provided shows.